# Vue.js 2 - retrieve form elements from server and render CRUD

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm Vue.js newbie and my task is:

- make an ajax call (GET) to server, using RESTful API (Laravel on background)
- retrieve a (JSON) list of Form CRUD items in array (like checkbox, input text, textarea...) with their properties (value, checked, custom classes...)
- **render CRUD form with these form items maybe using Vue's loop**

I'm wondering if it could be rendered using components somehow. But I don't know the correct way.

Frankly, I exactly don't know how to solve this problem with Vue.js - rendering items from array and each item has it's own markup and properties (checkbox has it's own, textbox, select, textarea...).

I'm building a web application based on CRUD operations and I'm trying to write universal components. The easiest way is to do a special component with hard-written sub-components for each subpage, but I don't like this way if not needed.

Thank you!

---

EDIT: I don't have much code yet, but this is where I am...

```
<script>
// ./components/CrutList.vue
    export default {
        mounted() {},

        data() {
            return {
                items: []
            }
        },

        props: ['resource'],

        methods: {
            getItems() {
                var resource = this.$resource('api/'+this.resource+'{/id}');

                resource.get({}).then(function(items){
                    if(items.body.status == 'success'){
                        this.items = items.body.items;
                    }
                }).bind(this);
            },

            deleteItem(item) {
                // perform CRUD operation DELETE
                alert('delete action');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My idea is using CrudList component to CRUD listing...

```
<crud-list resource="orders">
```

In laravel I do something like this:

```
return response()->json([
    'status' => 'success',
    'items' => [
        [
            'itemComponent' => 'checkbox',
            'props' => [
                'checked' => true,
                'label' => "Checkbox č.1",
                'name' => 'checkbox1'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'itemComponent' => 'checkbox',
            'props' => [
                'checked' => true,
                'label' => "Checkbox č.2",
                'name' => 'checkbox2'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'itemComponent' => 'checkbox',
            'props' => [
                'checked' => true,
                'name' => 'checkbox3'
            ]
        ],
    ],

]);
```

...it's very simplified, but it's just example of what I'm doing.
Now the problem is:

- take the 'itemComponent' part from the returned array item (this is in a loop),
- if it's a checkbox, take (for example) Checkbox.vue component, fill it with properties ('props' part of the array item)

I read about slots, but it's not what I'm looking for. Is there something I can use for dynamic components?

Comment: I added some code but truth is that I haven't much code yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this jsFiddle working example for dynamic forms: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/kr8w4n73/1/

You can do it easily by using a lot of `v-if`s for each and every form element type you might get from server. It is a bit cumbersome but I can't find any other way.

In the above example, I have the form structure as follows:

```js
var formItems = [{
    input_type: "text",
    input_label: "Login",
    values: {
        value: "your_name@example.com"
    }
},
{...},
{...}];
```

Once you have that data, then it is a matter of iterating through `formItems`, checking `input_type` and activating the relevant form control.

Here is how my dynamic form template looks like, for the above input:

```js
<div v-for="formItem in formValues">
    <div v-if="formItem.input_type == 'text'">
        <input type="text" v-model="formItem.values.value">
    </div>
    <div v-if="formItem.input_type == 'password'">
        <input type="password" v-model="formItem.values.value">
    </div>
    <div v-if="formItem.input_type == 'checkbox'">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="formItem.values.checked">
        {{formItem.values.label}}
    </div>
</div>
```

My jsFiddle example uses `form-horizontal` from bootstrap, and I am also able to display the labels well. If I put that in the example above, it will get cluttered and will not let you see how it works.

Hope it helps! You can change the `formItems` data structure to meet your needs, and modify the template accordingly.

Comment: It just works. Thank you very much. Maybe I have to think more simple :) This is very good answer for the goal I'm trying to achieve. Maybe there is no really need to have every form element as separated component...

Comment: @Michaelo Thanks for the feedback :-) It was a great challenge for me to spend time on, which I can use in some of my own apps in future.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort and willing to share this way of solving the problem. And jsFiddle really helped! :) I hope it will help others to create such application. This method allows us to avoid repeating code.

Comment: This is simple and great! Thank you!